# excel vba no code executed after Worksheets.add

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a bunch of tabs in a new workbook, with specific names taken from a range in another workbook. In the example below the first msgbox is executed but never the second. all of the tabs get created, but they don't get renamed.

```
Sub CreateInstructorSheet(r As Range)
  Dim tabname As String
  tabname = r.Offset(0, 1).Value
  MsgBox tabname + " 1"
  newtab = wb.Worksheets.Add
  MsgBox tabname + " 2"   
  newtab.Name = tabname
End Sub
```

I've also tried using Sheets.add, and providing parameters in the add statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason you haven't declared your `newtab` variable, and you are missing the `Set` keyword because you are trying to set `newtab` to a worksheet object.  You also never declared or assigned a value to the variable `wb`.

```
Sub CreateInstructorSheet(r As Range)

    Dim wb as Workbook
    Dim newtab as Worksheet
    Dim tabname As String

    Set wb = r.Parent.Parent    'The first parent is the range's worksheet
                                'The second parent is the worksheet's workbook

    tabname = r.Offset(0, 1).Value
    MsgBox tabname + " 1"

    Set newtab = wb.Worksheets.Add
    MsgBox tabname + " 2"

    newtab.Name = tabname    'Be very careful here, this can result in an error
                             'if a worksheet already exists with a name
                             'that is the value of tabname
End Sub
```

Comment: I had previously moved the dim statements out to the global declarations while I was trying to figure this out. It was just the set command I didn't know about. Thanks